# Manual Migration of a LEMP Wordpress site to a subdomain for testing/development

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain, development-environment

I am trying to manually migrate a wordpress site to a subdomain for development purposes. The site is too large to use the free WP migration tool.

How can I perform the migration manually via ssh?

Steps thus far completed:

-Subdomain created.
-MariaDB cloned.
-DNS and Nginx confirgured.
-Wordpress installed on subdomain and working.

From here, this is what I tried:

1. Backup.
2. via ssh copy all files from directory of mainsite to dev.mainsite folder EXCEPT wp-config.php
3. ???

My guess is doing a recursive find and replace of all instances of [://website.com] in the now cloned subdomain directory to ://dev.website.com , then all instances of [var/www/html/website] to be replaced with [var/www/html/dev.website]

I ended up trying this code, replacing php with each filetype within the dev subdomain directory:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/[mainsite]/[dev.mainsite]/g"

find . -type f -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/var/www/html/mainsite/var/www/html/dev.mainsite/g"
```

But I am not sure on the proper syntax to do these commands to avoid argument errors, and not break the sub.site -or if they are the right commands I am looking for

Am I even close? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your domain name should not be in template files: WordPress uses functions.

You should only have to have edit database.

Install [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org) - WordPress command line tool to convert `old.com` to `new.com`.

First: edit wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://new.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://new.com');
```

Second: replace info

WP-CLI [search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) command will convert serialized info.

Search for longest string first.

```
wp search-replace 'http://old.com' 'http://new.com' --all-tables --precise
```

Then all occurrences of old domain.

```
wp search-replace 'old.com' 'new.com' --all-tables --precise
```

That's it. You can login to new site.

Comment: This was very useful! After using this tool I stilI found a few instances of the original url in the wp content folders.  I was able to go thru and clean them up with the following from the new site root directory: `find . -type f -name ".php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s,https://oldsite,https://newsite,g"` `find . -type f -name ".css" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s,https://oldsite,https://newsite,g"`